# How do I pull the table I've made on SQL from the wider database into Databricks/Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, jupyter-notebook

I'm pulling information from the database on MySQL and I'm hoping to pull this in real time to Databricks/Jupyter so that I can produce individual Excels that matches certain criteria with Python. How should I do this?

I've saved the SQL query as a csv file to be read on Jupyter/Databricks but this won't be real-time and I'd have to resave the csv everytime i'm producing these Excels.